# How do I make a sound strip added programmatically to VSE channel through Blender Python API, not be muted anymore?

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor, audio

I wrote some python code to add a sound strip to Blender VSE at every runtime. The sound strip is indeed added as I wanted but it is muted, I cant hear the actual sound. I checked everything I could think of and find on the internet, but to no avail. The channel the strip was added on is not muted and the strip itself has volume 1.000.

Note: if I add the sound manually from Add -> Sound in VSE, then I can hear it fine, no problem. So it is not about the setting of Blender or my machine, it specifically has to do with the programmatic adding of sound strips.

```
from pydub.utils import mediainfo

bg_sound_filepath = f"{SOUND_VOICE_ROOT_DIR}/ambience.mp3"

# Check if the file exists
if os.path.isfile(bg_sound_filepath):
    # Add the sound strip
    sound_strip = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_sound(
        name="ambience",
        filepath=bg_sound_filepath, 
        channel=1,
        frame_start=1, 
    )

    # Update the scene's audio settings, just in case
    bpy.ops.sequencer.refresh_all()

    print("Sound strip added successfully.")
else:
    print(f"File {bg_sound_filepath} does not exist.")

# Get the duration of the sound file in seconds
sound_info = mediainfo(bg_sound_filepath)
sound_duration_seconds = float(sound_info['duration'])

# Set the duration of the sound strip to match the duration of the sound
sound_strip.frame_final_end = sound_strip.frame_final_start + int(sound_duration_seconds * bpy.context.scene.render.fps)
```

My app experience is dependent on these sound working properly.
How can I make this strip, or other strips added programmatically actually be heard from VSE?